Part of speech: "Thanks..."
I'm studying another language and can't quite get the translation right since I'm having trouble identifying the parts of speech for this sentence:

Thanks for the properly completed house

for=preposition
the=article
properly=adverb (which verb?)
completed=adjective
house=noun
I feel "thanks" is a noun but the way it's written is it shorthand for "I thank you..." thus making it a verb and allowing the adverb?  Or is the sentence above not really proper english.

Yes, thanks is a common way of saying thank you. Literally I give you thanks, so technically a plural noun.

Re "which verb?" -- adverbs can modify verbs, adjectives, or other adverbs. In this case it modifies the adjective "completed".

This might be more understandable if properly-completed had a hyphen. It's the house which has been completed properly, for which thanks are being offered.
